# Cannot access fields on second form angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I have a page in my app which contains a muti-step form.  To achieve this I have 3 forms in separate tabs. The js then only allows you to continue to the next step when the form your on successfully validates.

The first form is working perfectly and I've used the same structure on the second form too (as below).

```
<div class="stepped-content" ng-show="steps[steps_index.yourDetails].active">
  <form name="yourDetails" class="form-horizontal vs-onsubmit" ng-submit="submitForm('yourDetails')" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-form="organiser_name">
      <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Event organiser</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="organiser_name" ng-model="event.organiser_name" placeholder="You or your company's name." ng-required="true" />
        <div ng-messages="yourDetails.organiser_name.$error">
          <div ng-message="required">Please tell us who is organising this event.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

However when I print out `{{ yourDetails.organiser_name | json }}` it is undefined. `{{ yourDetails }}` itself is defined though:

```
{
  "$error": {},
  "$name": "yourDetails",
  "$dirty": false,
  "$pristine": true,
  "$valid": true,
  "$invalid": false,
  "$submitted": false
}
```

I'm struggling to see anything wrong with what I've written, so maybe I'm missing a rule that disallows more than one form in angular?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not more than one form, but the name of the form will be used to put the [`FormController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) onto the scope.

If you have two or more forms with the same `name` property, the last one processed will overwrite the previous ones.

Comment: Ah, I neglected to check the third form's name. Ah the dangers of copy-Paste. Thanks!